# How to get body value (drupal 7)

Tags: 7

I would access to the description of node in body value, so I try this :

```
// ----------------------------
// Acesseur de la descrition d'un noeud
// ---------------------------
function dfsi_GetBodyOf( $node )
{
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    return $wrapper->body->value();
}
// ----------------------------
// Acesseur de la criticite d'un noeud
// ---------------------------
function dfsi_GetCriticiteOf( $node )
{
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $wrapper-> field_criticite->value();    
return $wrapper;
}
```

I have no problems to access criticite value, but when I try to access body value, it return "array" and I don't know why, can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

The value of a formated text field is a structure with a `value` and a `format` property. Because the `body` is a formatted text, you likely need to use its `value` property. Tho get the formatted body value, you will need to use

```
$wrapper->body->value->value(array('sanitize' => TRUE))
```

Comment: Finaly i use it :
function dfsi_GetBodyOf( $node )
{
 $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
 $wrapper = $node->body['und'][0]['value'];
 return $wrapper;
}

Do you think it's better or not ?

Comment: If you are not using the entity_meta_date wrapper, then you should use field_get_items(). Otherwise, if you, or somebody else in a few month, start translating your content using the Entity Translation module, your code will stop working.
Also, you are loosing the `format` property of your body. Which means you cannot safely format the returned value (unless you only have one text format available, something a future developer may have to change in a few months).
So it is worse.

Comment: Thank you to answer. I'm in training in corporation, so i can't change all the code, but i will advertise about the problem